# How to fix Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

Have a MERN + Firebase app and getting this error and a bunch of  at `deepExtend (deepCopy.ts:71)`

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
getApps [as apps]
src/firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:172
  169 |  */
  170 | function getApps(): FirebaseApp[] {
  171 |   // Make a copy so caller cannot mutate the apps list.
> 172 |   return Object.keys(apps).map(name => apps[name]);
      | ^  173 | }
  174 | 
  175 | function registerComponent(
```

This is the JS file causing the issue. I cannot figure it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import axios from 'axios';
// import Product from '../components/Product';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { ReactMediaRecorder } from 'react-media-recorder';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseKeys from 'firebase';
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000';

dotenv.config();
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseKeys);
firebase.analytics();
export const storage = firebase.storage();

const AudioPreview = ({ stream }) => {
  const audioRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stream) audioRef.current.srcObject = stream;
  }, [stream]);

  if (!stream) return null;
  return <audio ref={audioRef} autoPlay controls />;
};

const VideoPreview = ({ stream }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stream) videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
  }, [stream]);

  if (!stream) return null;
  return <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay controls />;
};

function Controls({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl }) {
  const [url, setURL] = useState('');
  async function uploadFile() {
    const blob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then((r) => r.blob());
    const path = '/recordings/one';
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(path)
      .put(blob)
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded complete');
      });

    storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(setURL);
  }
  return (
    <Row>
      <span className='uk-text-meta'>{status}</span>
      <button className='uk-margin-small-left' type='button' onClick={startRecording} disabled={status === 'recording'}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button className='uk-margin-small-left' type='button' onClick={stopRecording} disabled={status === 'stopped'}>
        Stop
      </button>
      <button className='uk-margin-small-left' type='button' onClick={uploadFile} disabled={status !== 'stopped'}>
        upload
      </button>
      {url && (
        <a className='uk-margin-small-left' href={url} target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
          open
        </a>
      )}
    </Row>
  );
}

function RecordAudio() {
  return (
    <ReactMediaRecorder
      audio
      render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, previewStream, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
        <div>
          {status === 'recording' ? (
            <AudioPreview stream={previewStream} />
          ) : (
            <audio src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />
          )}
          <Controls
            status={status}
            startRecording={startRecording}
            stopRecording={stopRecording}
            mediaBlobUrl={mediaBlobUrl}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
}

function RecordVideo() {
  return (
    <ReactMediaRecorder
      video
      render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, previewStream, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
        <div>
          {status === 'recording' ? (
            <VideoPreview stream={previewStream} />
          ) : (
            <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />
          )}
          <Controls
            status={status}
            startRecording={startRecording}
            stopRecording={stopRecording}
            mediaBlobUrl={mediaBlobUrl}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
}

// function RecordScreen() {
//   return (
//     <ReactMediaRecorder
//       screen
//       render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
//         <div>
//           <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />
//           <Controls
//             status={status}
//             startRecording={startRecording}
//             stopRecording={stopRecording}
//             mediaBlobUrl={mediaBlobUrl}
//           />
//         </div>
//       )}
//     />
//   );
// }

function handleClick(num) {
  this.setState(num);
}

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  //const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  this.setState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('about to fetch product');
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      console.log('Below is the id param waht the fuck is it?');
      console.log(match.params.id);
      const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${match.params.id}`);

      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchProduct();
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on('status-update', function (call) {
      const stext = document.getElementById('statusText');
      stext.innerText = call;
    });
    // CLEAN UP THE EFFECT
    // return () => socket.disconnect();
  }, [match]);

  return (
    <>
      <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
        Go Back
      </Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`} />
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>Price : {product.price}</ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>Description : {product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Price: </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Status: </Col>
                  <Col>{product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button
                  //   onClick={addToCartHandler}
                  className='btn-block w-100'
                  type='button'
                  disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                >
                  Add To Cart
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Copy Status: </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <h2 id='statusText'>Share</h2>
                    <button type='button' onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
                      audio
                    </button>
                    <button type='button' onClick={() => handleClick(2)}>
                      video
                    </button>
                    {/* <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick(3)}>
        screen
      </button> */}
                    {state === 1 && <RecordAudio />}
                    {state === 2 && <RecordVideo />}
                    {/* {state === 3 && <RecordScreen />} */}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

Also, getting the Core Firebase JS SDK must alway be.... ERROR?

I have this in my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <title>Welcom To BShop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## UPDATE (firebase issue or reloading firebase again and again?)

If I comment out these 3 lines and any reference to **Storage**

Then the error goes away.

```
// firebase.initializeApp(firebaseKeys);
// firebase.analytics();
// export const storage = firebase.storage();
```

It isn't the analytics line!

Comment: It really helps us if you reduce your code to the bare minimum which causes the issue. This saves us from having to sift through all your code to figure out what's going on. Often times you end up finding the problem yourself simply by trying to isolate it. But without even reading your code, I bet you're triggering a `setState` from within a component render.

Comment: The use of `this.setState` in a function component as well as `handleClick` using `this.setState` tells me there are other issues here as well, or you're doing something highly questionable to make them work..

Comment: Are you sure `match` is not a new object every render/triggering the effect over and over again in combination with setting the product state? Based on the error, I'd say this is pretty likely..

Comment: Updated see above its Firebase?

Comment: Are you clicking the button in order to start the infinite loop or is it doing it without any interaction?

Comment: Just starting up when I hit the page

Answer (score 0):

OK, I left my comment above and then decided to see where you are calling `setState` - and you are doing it directly inside a component render. Here's the offending code:

```
const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  this.setState(0); // <- This is bad
  ...
}
```

Every time your ProductScreen renders, you are calling `setState`, which causes `ProductScreen` to render again, which then calls `setState` again, which causes `ProductScreen` to render again, which then calls `setState` again, which causes `ProductScreen` to render again, which then calls `setState` again, which causes `ProductScreen` to render again, which then calls `setState` again, which causes `ProductScreen` to render again, which then calls `setState` again, which causes `ProductScreen` to render again, which then calls `setState` again, which causes `ProductScreen` to render again, which then calls `setState` again.

---

You get the point. You should only call `setState` when something happens - like in a click handler or `useEffect` hook.

Comment: How is `this.setState` working from within a function component in the first place?

Comment: I removed that line and its still doing it.

Comment: @BrianThompson I immediately wondered the same. Seems suspect, yes, but since `this` is undefined in function components I think there should be an error being thrown there.

Comment: Again. That line has been removed. The issue appears to be around the Firebase lines?

Comment: I didn't read all of your code because there's too much going on. If you trim your code down to a minimal reproducible version, I'll take another look. There's something in there which is causing infinite renders... but I'm not going to look through all that code to find it. Also, you should not have `this` anywhere in your code since you are using functional components.